# How to make player to be able to rotate camera around cube in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-input

I have created new Unity project, have added a cube into the center and now want to make player to be able to rotate camera around this cube by swipes and/or mouse drags.

Please, name simple steps to implement this or keywords to find an answer or where to read about it?

Answer (score 3):

```
public Transform Target;

public float distance = 2.0f;
public float xSpeed = 20.0f;
public float ySpeed = 20.0f;
public float yMinLimit = -90f;
public float yMaxLimit = 90f;
public float distanceMin = 10f;
public float distanceMax = 10f;
public float smoothTime = 2f;
float rotationYAxis = 0.0f;
float rotationXAxis = 0.0f;
float velocityX = 0.0f;
float velocityY = 0.0f;

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        velocityX += xSpeed * Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * distance * 0.02f;
        velocityY += ySpeed * Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * 0.02f;
    }
    rotationYAxis += velocityX;
    rotationXAxis -= velocityY;
    rotationXAxis = ClampAngle(rotationXAxis, yMinLimit, yMaxLimit);

    Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.Euler(rotationXAxis, rotationYAxis, 0);

    Vector3 negDistance = new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, -distance);
    Vector3 position = rotation * negDistance + Target.position;

    transform.rotation = rotation;
    transform.position = position;
    velocityX = Mathf.Lerp(velocityX, 0, Time.deltaTime * smoothTime);
    velocityY = Mathf.Lerp(velocityY, 0, Time.deltaTime * smoothTime);
}

public static float ClampAngle(float angle, float min, float max)
{
    if (angle < -360F)
        angle += 360F;
    if (angle > 360F)
        angle -= 360F;
    return Mathf.Clamp(angle, min, max);
}
```

Taken from https://answers.unity.com/questions/1257281/how-to-rotate-camera-orbit-around-a-game-object-on.html

If you only want to rotate around a specific axis, for example around Y, you could basicly just do this

```
this.transform.RotateAround(Target.transform.position, Vector3.up, Input.GetAxis("Mouse X")*20.0f);
```

Comment: Where to write this? Why so complex? Can't I just listen for drag events and rotate my camera accordingly?

Comment: Create a new script, add this code, attach it to the camera. Assign the cube as the "Target" in the inspector view in unity. You could remove some complexity here, like removing the smoothing.

Comment: `fromRotation` never used

Answer (score 0):

Create a new C# Script called "CameraRotate", open it and paste this script:

```
    using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraRotate : MonoBehaviour {

    public Transform cube;

    public float sensitivityX;
    public float sensitivityY;
    GameObject pivot;

    void Start () {
        pivot = new GameObject ("pivot");
        pivot.transform.position = cube.position;
        transform.SetParent (pivot.transform);
    }

    void Update () {
        pivot.transform.eulerAngles += new Vector3 (Input.GetAxis ("Mouse Y") * -sensitivityX * Time.deltaTime, Input.GetAxis ("Mouse X") * sensitivityY * Time.deltaTime, 0);
    }
}
```

Assign this script to your camera, then in Inspector Tab, with the camera selected, assign your Cube (drag) into the "cube" slot, and assign a value to the sensitivity fields (i used something about 500), press play and test.

What does this script do?
It creates a new GameObject at the center of the Cube to be a reference of rotation, it's called pivot. So it sets the Camera as a child of the pivot, and rotates the pivot according with your mouse axis.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this way:

```
float mouseX = -Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
float mouseY = -Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");

float magnitude = transform.position.magnitude;

Vector3 mouseSwipe = new Vector3(mouseX, mouseY, 0);
Vector3 startPoint = new Vector3((float)camera.pixelWidth / 2, (float)camera.pixelHeight / 2, magnitude - 1);

Vector3 startPointWorld = camera.ScreenToViewportPoint(startPoint);
Vector3 endPointWord = camera.ScreenToViewportPoint(startPoint + mouseSwipe);

Vector3 mouseSwipeWord = endPointWord - startPointWorld;

float dragLat = mouseSwipeWord.y;
float dragLng = mouseSwipeWord.x;

Vector3 oldPosition = transform.position / magnitude;

float lat = Mathf.Asin(oldPosition.y);
float rsmall = Mathf.Acos(oldPosition.y);

float lng = Mathf.Atan2(oldPosition.z / rsmall, oldPosition.x / rsmall);

lat += dragLat * 10 * 2 * Mathf.PI;
if( lat*180/Mathf.PI > 80 )
{
    lat = 80 * Mathf.PI / 180;
}
else if( lat*180/Mathf.PI < -80)
{
    lat = -80 * Mathf.PI / 180;
}

lng += dragLng * 10 * 2 * Mathf.PI * 2;



float y = Mathf.Sin(lat);
rsmall = Mathf.Cos(lat);

float x = rsmall * Mathf.Cos(lng);
float z = rsmall * Mathf.Sin(lng);

Vector3 newPosition = new Vector3(x, y, z);
newPosition *= magnitude;

transform.position = newPosition;

LookAtTarget();
```

The goal was to simulate mouse is rotation object by drag.